# Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format/ speech to text view python

Tags: python, django, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

my speech to text view doesn't work and I have the file wav but I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\privet01\Desktop\python projects\projex x\myvev\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\privet01\Desktop\python projects\projex x\myvev\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\privet01\Desktop\python projects\projex x\alpha1\appsolve\views.py", line 636, in spechtotext
    with sr.AudioFile(sound) as source:
  File "C:\Users\privet01\Desktop\python projects\projex x\myvev\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 236, in __enter__
    raise ValueError("Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format")
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
[23/Aug/2021 13:26:44] "POST /spechtotext/ HTTP/1.1" 500 152359
```

**This is my view**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage



def spechtotext(request)   :
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.FILES['theFileINEEd']  and '.mp3' in  str(request.FILES['theFileINEEd'].name).lower() :
            
           
    
            myfile = request.FILES['theFileINEEd']
            fs = FileSystemStorage('')
          
            filename = fs.save(str(request.user)+"speachtotext.WAV", myfile)
           
            file_url = fs.url(filename)
            
            full_link='http://127.0.0.1:8000'+file_url # changeble to life mode 
         
  
            r = sr.Recognizer()

    
            print(type(filename))
            print('hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh')


             
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            import sys
            print(sys.version_info)
            
            
            print('qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq'+str(filename)+'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')

            hellow=sr.AudioFile(str(filename))
            sound = str(filename)
 
            
        
        
            with sr.AudioFile(sound) as source:
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        
        
                print("Converting Audio To Text ..... ")
        
        
                audio = r.listen(source)
        
        
        
            try:
                print("Converted Audio Is : \n" + r.recognize_google(audio))
        
        
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error {} : ".format(e) )


                
                audio_text = r.listen(source)


                
                try:
                    
                    # using google speech recognition
                    text = r.recognize_google(audio_text)
                    print('Converting audio transcripts into text ...')
                    print("this is the text : ",text)
                
                except:
                    print('Sorry.. run again...')   
                   

            return render (request,'appsolve/spechtotext.html',{'l5arij':request.FILES['theFileINEEd'],'link':file_url,'fulllink':full_link})   
        else:
            return render (request,'appsolve/spechtotext.html',{'problem':"you must upload a file mp3"}) 

    else:
        return render (request,'appsolve/spechtotext.html',)
```

**this is the error in the webpage**

[image]

and this is the file already in the same path
I try it with mp3 and PCM

[image]

I try it with a clear voice
but nothing changed the same error Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV ...